# Serializing events with circular references using ISerializable

Tags: c#, events, serialization, circular-reference, iserializable

I have to deal with serializing a bunch of objects. For the sake of simplicity I am using the `[Serializable]` attribute together with the binary serializer and binary formatter, excluding non-neccessary fields with `[NonSerialized]` for most of the stuff. For the more complex parts I implemented the `ISerializable` interface + a deserializing constructor. This works quite well, even when having circular references (in the form of *normal* object references).

Now I stubled over something that confuses me a bit. When a class `B` implementing `ISerializable`, and beeing referenced by another class (lets name it `Container`) subscribes to an event of that class, the `GetObjectData`-Method of `B` is called exactly twice when serializing.

```
[Serializable]
class Container
{
    B subObj;
    public int X;
    public event EventHandler E;

    public Container()
    {
        subObj = new B(this);
    }

}

[Serializable]
class B : ISerializable
{
    private Container parent;

    public B(Container parent) {
        this.parent = parent;

        parent.E += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(this.parent.X); };
    }

    protected B(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) { }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetObjectData");
    }
}
```

So this example code writes

```
GetObjectData
GetObjectData
```

For a problem with circular effects I'd have rather expected a stack overflow or something :-). Not good nonetheless. A workaround for this example would of course be re-adding the event in the deserializing constructor. But I'd like to get behind what causes this.

One last thing: If one changes the reference in the lambda expression above to the following (referencing the parameter, not the field)...

```
parent.E += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(parent.X); };
```

... serialization crashes with an `SerializationException` (*B+<>c__DisplayClass2 is not marked as Serializable*) right after the first time `GetObjectData` is executed.

Any hints for why (as well as useful workarounds) appreciated.

Comment: Serializing events is a very, very questionable practice.  It is not that it can't work, it is that it works so rarely without trouble.  You don't just get whatever object that contains the event serialized, you will also serialize the delegate targets, the objects that subscribed the event.  You have no guarantee whatsoever that these objects are actually serializable.  As you already found out from the lambda.  The point of events is that you *don't know* who subscribed them.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your reply - I see your pooint. In my case, however, I really know who subscribed the events as they are pretty much encapsulated. I could also use a manual handwritten invocation list (beeing aware of the references). But I wonder where this would cause a problem like above?